# How to get songs actual duration like "mm:ss" formate?

Tags: ios, audio, duration, seconds, minute

```
assetURL = [item valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
NSLog(@"%@", assetURL); // asset url declares the song url and song path

AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:assetURL options:nil]; // declare the audio asset url
CMTime audioDuration = audioAsset.duration; // get duration in cm time
double audioDurationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(audioDuration); // convert audio duration in double
```

But here is a problem because I get audio duration only in seconds but I need the "MM:SS" format for the song duration.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSUInteger audioDurationSeconds = (long)CMTimeGetSeconds(audioDuration);
NSUInteger minutes = floor(audioDurationSeconds % 3600 / 60);
NSUInteger seconds = floor(audioDurationSeconds % 3600 % 60);
NSString *time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld:%02ld", minutes, seconds];
```

Comment: NSString *time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld:%02ld", minutes, seconds];

Comment: That's a string you can use that string to either display or you can output it to console like `NSLog(@"%@", time);`

Comment: can i convert this time string into double ??